# Android Linkify stops getSelectedItemPosition() from working?

Tags: android, linkify

I have a ListView which has a TextView in the row. The TextView has been Linkified and has had setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()) set on it.

The ListView is no longer selectable and the ListView's getSelectedItemPosition() always return -1 .

Is there a way to know where the ListView has scrolled to in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`AdapterView#getFirstVisiblePosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition%28%29) it will return the position in the adapter for the first visible child view on the screen.